# Xcode remove simulator files

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-simulator

Team,

I am looking for an option to remove the unwanted old versions of simulator files. I have attached an image for reference, in the image you can see i have 3 variant of iOS 11 versions 11.0, 11.1 & 11.4

[image: Simulator]

How can i delete the unwanted ones from the list? I don't see any option in XCode. Does anyone figured this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using commandline with `simctl`.

First list your simulators with:

```
xcrun simctl list
```

There will be UUIDs of your simulators. Then you can delete a simulator with:

```
xcrun simctl delete <UUID>
```

Here's the output of `xcrun simctl help delete`:

> Delete specified devices, unavailable devices, or all devices.
> Usage: `simctl delete <device> [... <device n>] | unavailable | all`
>
> Specifying unavailable will delete devices that are not supported by the current Xcode SDK.

Comment: finally a working solution in 2022, thanks!

Comment: The output of `xcrun simctl list` is grouped by **Device Types**, **Runtimes**, **Devices**, and **Device Pairs**. Under which group will be the UUIDs of your simulators?

Answer (score 0):

There's a free Open Source App in the Mac App Store named [DevCleaner](https://apps.apple.com/in/app/devcleaner-for-xcode/id1388020431?mt=12) for Xcode which can possibly help you with this task.