# Xcrun: Invalid active developer path

Tags: xcode

While attempting to remove simulator files (see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/430140/xcode-remove-simulator-files?newreg=fa1c4416033a494a881a428c3e565850)), `xcrun simctl list` returns:

`xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun`

I never deleted any `xcrun` files, so what causes this, and how do I correct it?

Comment: Does the CLT include the simulators?  I didn't think so.

Comment: @Marc Wilson: I remember setting up unnecessary simulation files, and now, the `xcrun` isn't working? They have nothing to do with each other, yes, but it says `missing xcrun`. How do you correct _that_?

Comment: There has to be some sort of stub there... that's not an error from whatever shell you are using.  Myself, I would reinstall the CLT.